# ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: [PATH]: require() of ES Module from wdio-video-reporter.cjs not supported

Tags: node.js, automation, mocha.js, puppeteer, webdriver-io

VIdeo recording using wdio-video-reporter is not working with Webdriver.IO v7, hence igrating the webdriver, to v8.

After migration e2e testcases are working, but while configuring the wdio-video-reporter library in wdio.conf.js getting below error message. Other imports are working fine.

Complete ERROR:

```
ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: file:///D:/workspace/sample/mochascript/wdio.conf.ts: require() of ES Module D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\node_modules\@wdio\reporter\build\index.js from D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\dist\wdio-video-reporter.cjs not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\dist\wdio-video-reporter.cjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\node_modules\@wdio\reporter\build\index.js from D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\dist\wdio-video-reporter.cjs not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\dist\wdio-video-reporter.cjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:851:20)        
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\dist\wdio-video-reporter.cjs:3:20)   
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:851:20)        
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\wdio.conf.ts:7:47)
    at m._compile (D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:857:29)
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (D:\workspace\sample\mochascript\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:859:16) {      
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

[Link to webdriver.io v8 migration sample code where I am getting the error](https://github.com/sadabnepal/WebdriverIOTypeScriptMocha/tree/migerate_v8)

Comment: As far as I can see this is a bug in wdio. Related [ticket](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/9869)